# Incapsulating class with static wrapper method is good idea?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have been refactoring a huge method in the project I work and came up with this idea to create a validation service like this -

```
public class TrickyValidation {
    String validationVariable1;
    String validationVariable2;
    String validationVariable3;

    HashMap<String, Object> itemsMap;
    Object dependentObject;

    @Autowired
    SpringService service;

    public static boolean doTrickyValidation(HashMap<String, Object> itemsMap, Object dependentObject) {
        return new TrickyValidation(itemsMap, dependentObject).validate();
    }

    private TrickyValidation(Object itemsMap, Object dependentObject) {
        this.itemsMap = itemsMap;
        this.someDependentObject = dependentObject;
        init();
    }

    private boolean validate() {
        // loads of logic for validation by using validationVaribales
        return true;
    }

    private void init() {
        // Some methods to extract thease variables from itemsMap, dependentObject etc..
       this.validationVariable1 = service.get(dependentObject); 
       this.validationVariable1 = ...;
       this.validationVariable1 = ...;
    }
}
```

My goal what I want to do here is to Encapsulate everything as much as possible and use clean code principles.

- I feel a bit here like fighting spring framework because I don't want
  that "TrickyValidation" class would be @Servcie and belong to spring container. Will Autowired even work here?
- Is it a good design? Most likely I will use this validation in a loop. I like this solution because when I have to validate things I just simply call one and only public static method of this class `TrickyValidation.doTrickyValidation(map, obj)`

Any suggestions are welcome on how to improve this, or why it's a bad idea.

Comment: It kind of depends on how and where the validation is called. If it's from a Spring bean, you can create a validator bean from this and it will be autowired to the client.

Comment: It's not about validation, it's just an example. It's about encapsulating everything with one static method which calls the constructor and invokes action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code probably won't work because in the init method of the object you're trying to access `service` which is not autowired into this instance. In general the autowiring works only for objects managed (created by) Spring.

In this case you create "manually" the object of class `TrickyValidation`...

IMO the better design is to split the "Validator" object that can be Spring managed and the Validation itself that is not spring based.

```
@Component
public class Validator {

   @Autowired
   private Service service;

    public boolean doTrickyValidation(HashMap<String, Object> itemsMap, Object dependentObject) {
        // resolve the validation strategy from the items passed to this method.

        TrickyValidation validation = resolveTrickyValidation(itemsPam, dependentObject);

        return validation.validate();
    }

    private TrickyValidation resolveTrickyValidation(...) {
      // construct the proper validation strategy
      // access service if you want
    }



}
```

Comment: I guess I could get anything from spring container with: ```ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("springService", SpringService.class);```. Thank you for your suggestion. Maybe I just try to invent the wheel again here :D. What I like in my example, that everything is neat when you can use class variables. Readability increases greatly and you don't have to pass around a bunch of data in method parameters.

Comment: Its not a good practice to access applicationContext in your business code because the code becomes coupled to the spring framework...